# Python - Mock requests with side_effect

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to mock out the method `requests.get()` of the module `requests` and set the attribute `side_effect` of the obtained instance of the Mock class.
I would like to associate a different status_code for each side effect value but I didn't succeed so far.

```py
def test_func1(mocker):
    side_effect = ["Ok",'','','Failed']
    
    # This line should be changed
    fake_resp.status_code = 200
    
    fake_resp = mocker.Mock()
    fake_resp.json = mocker.Mock(side_effect=side_effect)       
    
    mocker.patch("app.main.requests.get", return_value=fake_resp)
        
    # func1 executes multiple API calls using requests.get()
    # and status_code is needed
    a = func1(a, b) 
    
    assert a == "something"
```

I have not been able to find a way (in the doc and SO) to associate the status_code for each mock request.

I was thinking about something like this but it's obviously not working:

```py
def test_func1(mocker):
    side_effect = [(status_code=200, return="Ok"),
                   (status_code=204, return=""), 
                   (status_code=204, return=""),
                   (status_code=500, return="Failed")]
    ....
```

---

**EDIT:** add the code of `func1()`

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests

def func1(days, delta_1):
    """
    days: number of days before first search (80, 25, 3)
    delta_1: number of days for the date range search (40, 20, 15)
    """
    now = datetime.now()
    start_date = now + timedelta(days=days)
    
    # Var to stop loop when price is found
    loop_stop = 0
    
    # Var to stop loop when search date is more than a year later
    delta_time = 0

    price = 0
    departureDate = "n/a"

    # For loop to check prices till one year. 
    while loop_stop == 0 and delta_time < (365 - days):
        date_range = (
            (start_date + timedelta(days=delta_time)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
            + "-"
            + (start_date + timedelta(days=delta_time + (delta_1 / 2))).strftime(
                "%Y%m%d"
            )
        )
        
        # Needs to be mocked
        response = requests.get("fake_url_using_date_range_var")
        
        if response.status_code == 204:
            print("No data found on this data range")
            delta_time += delta_1
        elif response.status_code == 200:
            price = response.json()["XXX"][0]
            departureDate = response.json()["YYY"][0]
            loop_stop = 1
        else:
            raise NameError(
                response.status_code,
                "Error occured while querying API",
                response.json(),
            )
        
    return price, departureDate
```

Comment: @frankfalse I just add the code of func1. Let me know if it's clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible solution with module `unittest` (not `pytest`)

I have written this answer before @baguette added the code of its function `func1()`, so I have created a file called `my_file_01.py` which contains **my production function** `func1()`:

```
import requests

def func1():
    response1 = 'empty1'
    response2 = 'empty2'
    r = requests.get('http://www.someurl.com')
    if r.status_code == 200:
        response1 = r.json()
    r = requests.get('http://www.some_other_url.com')
    if r.status_code == 500:
        response2 = r.json()
    return [response1, response2]
```

As you can see `func1()` calls `requests.get()` two times and checks the status code of responses.

I have inserted the **test code** in a different file with the following content:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from my_file_01 import func1

def request_resp1(url):
    response_mock = mock.Mock()
    response_mock.status_code = 200
    response_mock.json.return_value = {'key1': 'value1'}
    # the function return an instance of class Mock
    return response_mock

def request_resp2(url):
    response_mock = mock.Mock()
    response_mock.status_code = 500
    response_mock.json.return_value = "Failed"
    # the function return an instance of class Mock
    return response_mock

class TestFunc1(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch("my_file_01.requests")
    def test_func1(self, mock_requests):
        print("test func1()")
        mock_requests.get.side_effect = [request_resp1(""), request_resp2("")]
        [response1, response2] = func1()
        print("response1 = " + str(response1))
        print("response2 = " + str(response2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The test file defines the test class `TestFunc1` which contains the test method `test_func1()`.

Furthermore the file defines 2 functions called `request_resp1()` and `request_resp2()`.
These functions are used to define different response values when it is called the method `requests.get()` by the code of `func1()`; to be more accurate:

- the first call to `requests.get()` assigns to variable `r` the Mock object with `status_code = 200` so it simulates a success;
- the second call to `requests.get()` assigns to variable `r` the Mock object with `status_code = 500` so it simulates a failure.

If you try to execute the test code you can see that `func1()` return different values for the 2 different status_codes of the response. The output of the execution is composed by the 3 `print()` instructions present in `test_func1()` and is the followed:

```
test func1()
response1 = {'key1': 'value1'}
response2 = Failed
```

---

### Useful links

- For detail about `side_effect` attribute see [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect).
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74797315/mock-on-function-with-optional-arguments/74801225#74801225) is an other example with `side_effect`
- `request` is a Python module and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_requests.asp) is a minimal documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution from @frankfalse, the two mocking functions can be replaced by a class.

```
class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, json_data, status_code=requests.codes.ok):
        self.json_data = json_data
        self.status_code = status_code

    def json(self):
        return self.json_data
```

With the previous class the file contained the test code of @frankfalse becomes:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from my_file_01 import func1
import requests

class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, json_data, status_code=requests.codes.ok):
        self.json_data = json_data
        self.status_code = status_code

    def json(self):
        return self.json_data

class TestFunc1(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch("my_file_01.requests")
    def test_func1(self, mock_requests):
        print("test func1()")
        mock_requests.get.side_effect = [MockResponse({'key1': 'value1'}), MockResponse('Failed', 500)]
        [response1, response2] = func1()
        print("response1 = " + str(response1))
        print("response2 = " + str(response2))
```

The differences are:

- the mocking functions `request_resp1()` and `request_resp2()` can be removed
- it is necessary to add: `import requests` for the presence of the assignment `status_code=requests.codes.ok` in the `__init__()` method
- the instruction for the definition of `side_effect` becomes:
  `mock_requests.get.side_effect = [MockResponse({'key1': 'value1'}), MockResponse('error', 500)]`

Because ith has been created the class `MockResponse`, the class `Mock` of the module `unittest.mock` is not used.