# How to mock a function varying the number of invocations and optional arguments?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, optional-parameters

I want to write a test for "A" function which calls another "B" function in it. B function looks like this:

```
def Bfuncion(self, city: Optional[str], name: Optional[str]):
```

in A function I use B function two times, first time I use it in this way:

```
cities = self.Bfunction(name=None, city="ny", page=page)
```

and the second time in this way:

```
cities = self.Bfunction(name="Tom", city=None, page=page)
```

Now I want to write a test of A function. The test must to verify if there is only one use of the B function:

```
mocker.patch("Path.To.My.Function",return_value=[{"value1"},{"value2"},{"value3"}],...
```

How do I write call `mocker()`, as I use B function with different arguments in each call.

Answer (score 0):

I try to suggest you a solution for your test; I don't know if it is suited for your need because I have tried to guess some details that you have omitted in your question.

### The production code

I suppose that your production code is contained in a file called `functions.py` and the content of `functions.py` is the following:

```
from typing import Optional

class MyClass:

    def Bfunction(self, city: Optional[str], name: Optional[str]):
        return city

    def Afunction(self):
        cities = self.Bfunction(name=None, city="ny", page='page')
        print(cities)
        cities = self.Bfunction(name="Tom", city=None, page='page')
        print(cities)
```

Note that in `functions.py`:

1. I have defined a class because I have seen that your definition of the `Bfunction` contains the `self` argument.
2. The `Afunction` executes the two calls of `Bfunction` that you have written in your question.

### The test file

The test file (which doesn't use `pytest` but only the module `unittest`) is the following:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import functions

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        sut = functions.MyClass()
        with mock.patch.object(sut, 'Bfunction') as mock_b:
            # set values returned by Bfunction in the first and in the second call
            mock_b.side_effect = ['cityA', 'cityB']
            sut.Afunction()
            # here I verify that Bfunction is called 2 times
            self.assertEqual(2, mock_b.call_count)

            # here I verify the arguments of the Bfunction 2 calls
            self.assertDictEqual({'name': None, 'city': 'ny', 'page': 'page'},
                                 mock_b.call_args_list[0][1])
            self.assertDictEqual({'name': 'Tom', 'city': None, 'page': 'page'},
                                 mock_b.call_args_list[1][1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### The output of test file execution

The output of the test file execution is:

```
cityA
cityB
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

The output showes:

1. `Afunction` calls exactly two times the `Bfunction`
2. the test verify the arguments passed to `Bfunction` by the use of the attribute `call_args_list`
3. the presence of `cityA` and `cityB` in the output show you how to select different values returned by `Bfunction` (you have to use `side_effect` and not `return_value`).

I hope that this answer is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `side_effect` keyword argument, not the `return_value` keyword argument.

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock
>>> m = Mock(return_value=[1,2,3])
>>> m()
[1, 2, 3]
>>> m = Mock(side_effect=[1,2,3])
>>> m()
1
>>> m()
2
>>> m()
3
```

(`patch`, of course, simply passes keyword arguments it does not itself recognize to `Mock` to configure the object that is used by the patched name.)

This requires you to know ahead of time the order of calls that will be made. If you need more flexibility, patch the name with a custom function that behaves the way you want, instead of a `Mock` object.

```
def my_func(self, name, city, page):
    ...
mocker.patch(
    "Path.To.My.Function",
    new=my_func
)
```